# How to Configure Flocker on centos 7.2?

Tags: docker, centos7, large-data-volumes, docker-swarm-mode, flocker

I used https://media-glass.es/flocker-on-centos-7-17a8bfaa6509 as reference for installing ,But the yum repo is not available now. And if you have any alternatives for **flocker** please share. I am looking for an open-source container data volume manager for your Dockerized application/services.